# How do I wrap a remote executable in an sh_binary in Bazel?

Tags: bazel

Suppose I have a tool hosted on an HTTP server. I would like to use this tool in Bazel build rules as an `sh_binary`.

How do I get Bazel to the following?

1. Download the tool
2. Unpack it (it is a zip)
3. Wrap the executable in an `sh_binary`
4. Use the `sh_binary` in an `sh_test` or a `genrule`

So far I have only achieved step (1), which is to fetch the archive:

`WORKSPACE`

```py
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_file")

http_file(
  name = "fantomas_nuget",
  sha256 = "98f2604859a377687c9a63b5a0148a47153224f19856142cc20705a96e1ea211",
  urls = [ "https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/fantomas/5.0.0-alpha-010" ],
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using [rules_dotnet](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_dotnet)? It has some tools for using nuget packages:
https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_dotnet/blob/master/docs/nuget2bazel.md

In particular, this package has [two dependencies](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Fantomas/#dependencies-body-tab)

```
FSharp.Compiler.Service (= 41.0.3)
FSharp.Core (>= 6.0.3)
```

I don't know if you get those automatically from the F# runtime environment, but if those are needed, http_file / http_archive won't download those dependencies.

I notice that this is a code formatter. Note that in general, bazel actions (e.g. genrule and other rule actions) aren't designed to modify the source tree.

Coincidentally, there was just recently a thread on bazel-discuss that discussed formatters and linters:
https://groups.google.com/g/bazel-discuss/c/GXyZkKEzgTE/m/mjvUQS5CAQAJ

---

Something like this might get you started:

`WORKSPACE`:

```
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")

http_archive(
  name = "fantomas_nuget",
  type = "zip",
  build_file = "@//:BUILD.fantomas",
  sha256 = "98f2604859a377687c9a63b5a0148a47153224f19856142cc20705a96e1ea211",
  urls = [ "https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/fantomas/5.0.0-alpha-010" ],
)
```

`BUILD.fantomas`:

```
filegroup(
    name = "fantomas",
    srcs = glob([
        "**/*.dll",
        "**/*.xml",
        "**/*.json",
    ]),
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```

`BUILD`:

```
sh_binary(
  name = "fantomas",
  srcs = ["fantomas.sh"],
  data = ["@fantomas_nuget//:fantomas"],
)

sh_test(
  name = "sources_test",
  srcs = ["test_sources.sh"],
  data = [
      "my_fsharp_file",
      ":fantomas",
  ],
  args = ["$(location my_fsharp_file)"],
)
```

`test_sources.sh`:

```
echo Running the test
fantomas $@
```

`fantomas.sh`:

```
echo args:
echo $@

echo
echo find:
find .

echo
echo stat:
stat $@

echo
echo line count:
wc -l $@
```

`my_fsharp_file`:

```
F#
```

Comment: I am not using rules_dotnet since they are not quite production ready. I hope to fetch the dotnet tool as a zip and run it. The idea is to check the formatting using Bazel as a test, not modify the source files.

Comment: Should also mention that dotnet tool packages on nuget have all dependencies included.

Comment: I added an example that might get you started